# How to color one of the table layout pannel controls in c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I've created a Windows Form which looks like this:
[My Windows Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWMb4.png)

What I want to do is to color one of these numbered buttons by passing its number to the Form constructor. Here is what I've tried to do, but there are no visible changes. Any suggestions?

```
public SeatSelection(string seatNumber)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(Control ctrl in this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.Text == seatNumber)
            {
                ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

The if statement does find true, and the BackColor does change, but the form wont update:
[Watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA2Dn.png)

Comment: Some more information about the problem would be helpful. When you step through the code does it find a ctrl.Text == seatNumber and execute the ctrl.BackColor statement, or is does the if statement never find a true condition? In other words, Is the if failing, or is setting the BackColor failing?

Comment: Posted code works.  Use the debugger to step through the code to see what is happening.

Comment: I think that at this point (form constructor) the controls in a form are not fully loaded. Did you try doing it at Form.Load event? You could store the seat number in a variable, set at the constructor, and use it at the Form.Load event. But you can also debug your constructor code to check if the buttons already have their text properties set.

Comment: Is the button's FlatStyle set to System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, my bad. This code was fine. I made a mistake somewhere else. I did not realised that I called the default constructor immediately after calling this one. Missed else keyword in my if statement, so it was

```
int seatNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtSeatNumber.Text);
if(seatNumber>=1 && seatNumber<=21)
            seats = new SeatSelection(txtSeatNumber.Text);
        seats = new SeatSelection();
        seats.Show();
```

Instead of

```
int seatNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtSeatNumber.Text);
if(seatNumber>=1 && seatNumber<=21)
            seats = new SeatSelection(txtSeatNumber.Text);
        else
            seats = new SeatSelection();
        seats.Show();
```